# Rename Filename script

Tags: scripting

I'm using the below script to change the second character on a list of filenames on a directory. It will basically change the filename as follow:

GA001001   >   GX001001
GA001002   >   GX001002
GA001003   >   GX001003

and so on until all of them are changed or renamed.

I tried this script first, but didn't work.

```
#!/bin/ksh

# Script for InfoPrint OVERLAY file convertion for 600 dpi
# Last Updated 02/29/2012
# By Harry Marion
for x in *"A"*; do
  mv -- "$x"A"${x// /X}"
done
```

Then I tried this one, but didn't work either.

```
#!/bin/ksh

# Script for InfoPrint OVERLAY file convertion for 600 dpi
# Last Updated 02/29/2012
# By Harry Marion
for x in *"A"*; do
  mv -- "$x"A"${x//A/X}"
done
```

Comment: You may want to say what error messages you get, but in any case, your script seems to give the `mv` command a single argument, although it needs at least two. Is the second character always an A? And the first character is always a G, or at least never an A?

Comment: A foolproof solution to only change the second character is something like `x=$(echo "$x" | sed 's/^\(.\)./\1X/')`, but depending on the structure of those filenames, a simpler solution could exist.

Comment: @berndbausch this isn't foolproof when there's a path involved - e.g. `x=PathToFile/File`.  Still can be done with sed though

Comment: The question is about a list of filenames in a directory, where the character to be changed is always at the second position. Thus, `cd /path` before the `sed` command is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't force a one-liner if you don't need one:

```
for i in GA* ; do
    j="${i/GA/GX}"
    echo mv "$i" "$j"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Specs:-

> I'm using the below script to change the second character on a list of filenames on a directory.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for x in ?A*; do
  case $x in
    A*) mv -f -- "$x" "${x/AA/AX}" ;;
     *) mv -f -- "$x" "${x/A/X}"
  esac
done
```